# Ruby ouput(string and integers)

Tags: ruby, shell

I have to output(string & integers) something like this on the same line: Sat, 7 May 2016 15:27:40 -0400

This is what I'm running to output.

```
print "\tCreated On: "+(package["created"] == nil ? "" : package["created"]).to_s + "\n";
```

But my output is returning like this.

```
Created On: 1462649260418
```

Comment: That time is May 7th, 2016?

Comment: I just need to output day/date/year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
print "\tCreated On: #{Time.at(package['created'].to_i / 1000).strftime('%d/%b/%Y') unless package["created"].nil?}\n"
```

Comment: I just had to put in double-quotes to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is a timestamp you need to convert it to a time. That looks like a millisecond epoch timestamp, so you can convert it with:

```
Time.at(package['created'] / 1000)
```

Then use `strftime` to format as required.

Comment: I just need to output Day/Date/Year

Comment: You can use [whatever format you want](https://www.foragoodstrftime.com) with `strftime`.